# How do I use a var to access json object property

Tags: javascript, json

So here's a little test I'm doing to check if I'm grabbing all the thumbs from my object. Problem is projectName is coming up undefined. Whhhhaaa?

```
var projectName = $(this).attr("href"); 

console.log(worklist.work.projectName.thumbs.length);
```

Comment: Is that all the code?  What is `$(this)` referring to?

Comment: The a that is clicked.

Comment: What @hkpeprah said. If you're doing the console.log where this shows it, you wouldn't be in the right context to call it like that.

Comment: Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

Comment: I suggest that you log `this` to the console to see what attributes it has.

Comment: A jsfiddle or working snippet would make this question much more answerable.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access a property dynamically, use [bracket-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).

```
console.log(worklist.work[projectName].thumbs.length);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Curious though as to why you need . after the bracket notation.

Comment: @seguraMode You don't. You do, however, if you want to access the `length` property of the `thumbs` property of whatever's stored in `worklist.work[projectName]`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
console.log(worklist.work[projectName].thumbs.length);
```